# How do I find the standard deviation of a normal distribution, given mean, threshold, and probability?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy

Using `scipy.stats.norm()`, I want to find the standard deviation (`scale`) that satisfies these requirements:

`loc=0`, `P(X≤-5)=0.2`

Until now, I've been solving this through trial and error:

```
sd = 5.95 # change until requirement is met
stats.norm(loc=0,scale=sd).cdf(-5) # this should eventually reach about 0.2
```

If it's not possible with `scipy.stats.norm()`, I'm open to new suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your given `x` and `p`, the expression that you want is `x / norm.ppf(p)`.  (The method `ppf` is the "percent point function", more commonly called the inverse CDF or the quantile function.)

For example,

```
In [76]: from scipy.stats import norm

In [77]: x0 = -5

In [78]: p0 = 0.2

In [79]: scale = x0 / norm.ppf(p0)                               

In [80]: scale                                                                                                           
Out[80]: 5.940914749469451

In [81]: norm.cdf(x0, scale=scale)                                                                                       
Out[81]: 0.19999999999999996
```